# What is the right term for the metal bar used as an underneath of iron ramming?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I have to search some images of the metal bar which can be used as an underneath of iron ramming. But I don't know the exact word of it to construct my search query. Can anyone tell me the exact name of it?

It looks something like this,

[image]

Comment: http://www.walmart.com/ip/33348135?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227024601254&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40839430352&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=78652733312&veh=sem

Comment: http://www.sears.com/craftsman-2-1-2-ton-floor-jack-low-profile/p-00950165000P?sid=IDx01192011x000001&kpid=00950165000&kispla=00950165000P&kpid=00950165000&mktRedirect=y

Comment: http://www.craftsman.com/shc/s/p_10155_12602_00950357000P?sid=IDxCMDFx20140801x001&KPID=00950357000&kpid=00950357000

Comment: @BlessedGeek No I'm not looking for this. You might have seen tom and jerry cartoons. There one metal bar used to fall over tom's head most often. That is the one i am looking for.

Comment: The thing you do on an anvil is generally referred to as "forging" (though purists would insist that the metal must first be heated red hot for it to count as "forging").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is [anvil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anvil):

> - A heavy block of iron or steel with a smooth, flat top on which metals are shaped by hammering.:

[image]

[Anvil pictures](https://www.google.it/search?q=anvil&biw=768&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=z-ocVYirJISuU-fVgbAI&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&dpr=2#imgrc=_)

Comment: There are also alternate terms for specialized (and usually smaller) anvil-like devices (though none of them are coming to me just now).